# Как достать декодировать русское слово?

Tags: php, laravel

В запросе приходит слово на русском языке. Нужно достать из него первый символ и вернуть. Как это сделать?

```
//$word = абвгд
$word = $request->input('word');
$s = $word[0];
return $s;
```

В итоге приходит ошибка:

> InvalidArgumentException: Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded in file /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/JsonResponse.php on line 75

Как декодировать слово, чтобы можно было работать с символами.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mb-substr.php

Comment: @АйратИсмагилов `$str = mb_convert_encoding($s, 'UTF-8');`

Comment: $str = mb_convert_encoding($s, 'UTF-8');  return $str; не декодирует, вернул: "\u0430\u0431\u0432\u0433\u0434"

Comment: return mb_substr($s,0,2); выдал 2 закодированных символа: "\u0430\u0431"

Comment: mb_substr($s,0,1); вернет один :)

Comment: Мне нужно раскодировать строку, всёравно возвращается закодированный символ "\u0430"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934563/how-to-decode-unicode-escape-sequences-like-u00ed-to-proper-utf-8-encoded-cha

Comment: или так `$chr = preg_replace('/\\\u0([0-9a-fA-F]{3})/','&#x\1;',$chr);
echo  html_entity_decode($chr, ENT_NOQUOTES,'UTF-8');`